# Overall test significance in logistic regression

Tags: r, testing, logistic-regression

How can I compute overall siginificance in logistic regression in R? I'd like to compare my logit model with model that contains only constant term.

Answer (score 1):

You can use anova to compare against the intercept only model:

```
data = iris
data$Species = factor(ifelse(data$Species=="versicolor","v","o"))
fit = glm(Species ~ .,data=data,family=binomial)
fit0 = glm(Species ~ 1,data=data,family=binomial)

anova(fit0,fit,test="Chisq")
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: Species ~ 1
Model 2: Species ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance  Pr(>Chi)    
1       149     190.95                          
2       145     145.07  4   45.885 2.603e-09 ***
```